# Replace a string in the file outside curly braces only

Tags: bash, awk, replace, sed, curly-braces

I need to replace some strings in the file but when the string is inside curly braces, i need to skip it. Something like

```
sed -i '/[^{].*foo.*[^}]/ s/foo/bar/g' test.f
```

test file test.f contains something like this:

```
bar foo {foobar}bar {foo}
```

This should search only for foo in the string which is not wrapped in the braces. So the result should be:

```
bar bar {foobar}bar {foo}
```

Everything in the braces should be ignored, i.e. if the string starts with "{" it should be ignored until the corresponding "}" in the line.

This doesn't have to be performed by sed. Thanks a lot.

Sample Input:

```
bar foo {foobar}bar {foo}
foo { foo { foo } foo } foo
foo { foo } foo { foo } foo
```

Expected Output:

```
bar bar {foobar}bar {foo}
bar { foo { foo } foo } bar
bar { foo } bar { foo } bar
```

Comment: What should happen to strings like `bar { foo` or `foo } bar`?

Comment: What should happen to nested curlies? `foo { foo { foo } foo } foo` versus `foo { foo } foo { foo } foo`.

Comment: Please update the question with the info asked in the above comments. The question itself is not clear at the moment..

Comment: Basically anything inside braces should be ingored, doesn't matter if there are another braces inside. Therefore the result for your example would be  bar { foo { foo } foo } bar and  bar { foo } bar { foo } bar.

Comment: Using shell utilities it is impossible to find a matching closing `}` when `{` and `}` are nested.

Comment: @anubhava no it's not. Maybe you meant to say "...with one regexp" or something.

Comment: Yes Ed, that is what I meant that using a single regex it is next to impossible using standard shell utilities.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    gsub(/foo/,RS)
    numChars = length()
    rec = ""
    for (charNr=1; charNr<=numChars; charNr++) {
        char = substr($0,charNr,1)
        if ( char == "{" ) { depth++ }
        if ( char == "}" ) { depth-- }
        rec = rec ((char == RS) && (depth == 0) ? "bar" : char)
    }
    gsub(RS,"foo",rec)
    print rec
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
bar bar {foobar}bar {foo}
bar { foo { foo } foo } bar
bar { foo } bar { foo } bar
```

Comment: This is the right way to go instead of any regex based solution ++

Comment: Is it?. Furthermore gsub() is even used twice per line here

Comment: Calling gsub() twice per line isn't a problem. We'll see if anyone comes up with a regexp based solution for comparison.

Comment: check my.. I admit that I'm just curious. Likely I'll loose that race

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun!

```
awk '{sub(/foo/,"bar")}{sub(/ foo$/," bar")}{sub(/} foo {/,"} bar {")}1' file
bar bar {foobar}bar {foo}
bar { foo { foo } foo } bar
bar { foo } bar { foo } bar
```